# How to detect "network idle" situation in perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, networking, debian

I would like to detect low usage of easily saturated network link to execute one of many small tasks. It is single comp over single ppp link situation.

network idle - e.g. 2 minutes of link use with peak use below 1% of maximum theoretical speed

I prefer receiving notifications over periodic polling and solution simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing for network being 'idle' is difficult, because it depends *where* your bottleneck lies.

- If it's on your host:

  use `ifconfig` to look at TX/RX bytes, and see the rate at which it's changing.
- if it's on your switch or further upstream:

  you need to gather this information somehow, such as with SNMP.

Otherwise, there's simply no way to measure how idle a network is.

You *can* detect saturation, by looking at response times to `ping` - ping times increase when a network is saturated - but there's not really any way to tell the difference between a network below 60% capacity or so. (As a very rough rule of thumb, congestion starts to increase latency at about 60% utilisation).

Comment: I had hoped for something more clever than `ifconfig` polling.

Comment: I asked the question to avoid reinventing the wheel.